# Enrolled in or at

Tags: grammar, prepositions

1. I got enrolled ‘in’ university.
2. I got enrolled ‘at’ university.

Which preposition is correct here?

Comment: I think the second one is correct. Take a look at this link. `https://www.gonaturalenglish.com/tackling-tricky-prepositions/`